# Hhow to prove the equivalence between open set and interior on a topological space.

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, proof-writing, proof-explanation

Let $X$ be a topological space with topology $T$ described by open sets, defining the interior of a subset $A$ of $X$ to be the set whose is the union of all open sets that are subsets of A, then we should have an equivalence between be open and a set be equal to it own interior.

In order to prove this is necessary to show that if the set $A$ is contained in its own interior then it is open. I did a proof using the already know statement that $A$ contains it interior and then since the interior is union of open sets in a topologicla space it should be open and since $A$ is equal to an open set it is also an open set.

My problem with this is because there is no intuition here, and it as a mechanical proof, i am seaking a meaning on this, what does it mean that a set $A$ is subset of its interior? Why should A be open??

Comment: I disagree: the argument that you gave *is* intuitive. You know that $\operatorname{int}A$ is a subset of $A$, because it’s a union of subsets of $A$. When you say that $A\subseteq\operatorname{int}A$, you automatically are saying that $A\subseteq\operatorname{int}A\subseteq A$ and hence that $A=\operatorname{int}A$. You know that $\operatorname{int}A$ is open, because it’s a union of open sets, so it follows immediately that $A$ is open.

Comment: I assume that viweing A⊆intA⊆A cleared the idea. But just to confirm, in an applied situation, it is not so simple obtain that A⊆intA, is it?

Comment: I can’t think of a situation in which one would want to do so. Typically either $A$ is open, in which case it equals its interior, or $A$ isn’t open, in which case $\operatorname{int}A\subsetneqq A$. As a general rule one worries about the interior of a set when the set isn’t open, since we know exactly what the interior is when the set *is* open.

Comment: You’re welcome!